# Javascript sorting with callbackss

Tags: javascript, callback, usability

I have several links for sorting current elements on page.

Functions:

- A - click handler with array sort
- B - display elements according to sorted array.

Sorting can take even 2 seconds, so I want to display some feedback to user.

I thought about change link text to 'In progress..' or something like that.

In fun A store old link text and change it to 'In progress' and pass another function to B
that I invoke after display elements to show old text of link, but it just doesn't work.

In debugger link text is changed, but I can see only old text all the time.

How can I create valid callback for this?

I see websites with similar sorting and without any feedback to user too.

Is this possible to do with javascript? Or feedback can be display only on ajax request?

Comment: mhm... if you change the link text before starting the sort imho this should work. Can you post some code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you're running entirely ***synchronous*** code.

The DOM does not update until whatever function(s) you've started have completed (even if you update the DOM before the long running calculation).

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/uwuxez/edit#javascript,live) of a long running calculation that prevents the DOM from updating immediately. *(Click the "Render" button at the top to see the example properly.)*

Notice in the example that the `"Starting... Wait a few seconds."` text appears immediately, and is not blocked by the long running calculation. But the `"Updated"` text takes 3 seconds to appear.

The reason for this is because I added the `"Starting..."` to the DOM first, then wrapped the rest of the code in a `setTimeout`. This allowed the DOM to update immediately for `"Starting..."`, but the rest of the code *within* the `setTimeout` is *synchronous*, so the DOM won't update again until that code is complete.

---

So your solution can be to update the text with `"In progress..."`, then wrap the rest of the code in a `setTimeout()` in order to allow the DOM to update immediately with your progress message.

```
element.innerHTML = "In progress...";

setTimeout( function() {
    // invoke the sorting code
}, 0);
```